# Cakephp 3.0 Passing value from one controller to other

Tags: cakephp, controller

Hey I am facing some problem I want to pass a value from on controller to the other so that I can create and update view using certain user id restricted I am trying to create a simple messaging system where user a can talk to user b in seperate controller

Comment: You should expand a little bit more on your question here if you want more detailed help... You could perhaps do a redirect `return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'another-controller', 'action' => 'edit', $id]);`

Comment: my question is can I pass id in other controller like we do in php procedural I have two ids in my one controller and I want to move it to other controller can do it by session and that id can we access by all action of controller

Comment: Yeah, your best bet then is to place it them in SESSION and then pick it up in the other controller...

Comment: how to put ids in session and get it in other controller I mean how to move data from one controler to other via seesion

Comment: See answer below with some code examples

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to use the Configure class... more details here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html. Here is an example:

In Controller 1:

```
Configure::write('ids', [
    'id1' => $id1,
    'id2' => $id2
]);
```

And in Controller 2:

```
// would print the value of $id1
echo Configure::read('ids.id1'); 

// would print the value of $id2
echo Configure::read('ids.id2');
```

The document listed above is pretty detailed, but if you need further help, let me know and I will try to walk you thru your own case.